# How to filter kendo grid with a column that contains multiselect - multiple values?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a multiselect grid column same as onabai (awesome guy on so!) I need to put filter menu on that column.

http://onabai.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/kendoui-multiselect-in-a-grid-yes-we-can/

I have added custom filter on the multivalue column

```
  filterable: {
    ui: function(element) {
      element.kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: [ "London", "Surat", "New York"]  //etc
      });
    }
```

The filter shows up on the grid column but the filter does not filter. 
I guess, I need to somehow capture the filter change event and filter data source based on value selected.

Any pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: I ended up creating new column with parse method that creates displayValue for the column to be edited and used editor template with multiselect bound to the actual field that can be modified.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you achieved this?

Answer (score 3):

This took me a while to grasp but you can use kendoGrid custom filters for this.

I've created a function to setup the multiselect as the UI and its filter function:

```
function userFilter(element) {
console.log(element);
element.removeAttr("data-bind");
  //$scope.kGrid.dataSource.query({ filter: filter });

  $scope.userFilterElement = element.kendoMultiSelect({
      dataSource: $scope.users,
      optionLabel: "--Select Value--",
      change: function(e){
        var filter = { name: "user", logic: "or", filters: [] };
        var values = this.value();
        $.each(values, function(i, v) {
          filter.filters.push({field: "user", operator: "eq", value: v });
        });
        //$scope.kGrid.dataSource.filter(filter);
        if ($scope.gridFilter.filters[0] && $scope.gridFilter.filters[0].name == 'user'){
          if (filter.filters.length > 0)
            $scope.gridFilter.filters.splice(0,1,filter);
          else
           $scope.gridFilter.filters.splice(0,1);

        }
        else
          $scope.gridFilter.filters.push(filter);
        $scope.kGrid.dataSource.filter($scope.gridFilter);
      }
  });
```

}

That's a relatively crude and basic example which I simplified for the sake of easier code reading.
Here's a working code: http://plnkr.co/edit/8N1oNpsd10CJwBrWKpK3?p=preview
After the grid loads, click on "add data" a few times, and then filter the users and use multiple variables.
Hope this helps.